# "(13)Permission denied" error from Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, http-status-code-403

This is an Apache server on Linux RH ES 5.6. I created a new Apache instance on port 443.

When I try to access the website I get a 403 error. I see the following in my error logs:

```
$ vi controlnetworx-int2_error_log.1336608000
[Tue May 15 15:07:07 2012] [error] [client 10.13.137.80] (13)Permission denied: access to / denied
[Tue May 15 15:09:05 2012] [error] [client 10.13.137.80] (13)Permission denied: access to / denied
```

I gave the user permission with `chmod 777 ..server/htdocs`, but this didn't get rid of the `(13)Permission denied` error.

Comment: You certainly don't want 777, that is pretty much never the correct permissions.  You probably want that to be 755.  Its not going to be the case that accessing the website requires write permission to the document root.

Comment: can you include the output of `httpd -S` which should show us the basics of how your server is configured?

Answer (score 2):

This error is because of SELinux. Run this:

```
chcon -R -h -t http_sys_content_t /path/to/your/htdocs
```

After that, you wouldn't get the 403 error.